# How can I change task color in Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar

I have google calendar with google tasks enabled.

I want to change color of some tasks.

For example most important tasks will have red color and all others tasks will have blue color.

So how can I change task color in Google Calendar?

(you can say that I can use events instead of tasks (it is possible to change event color), but then I can't mark "event" as completed, what I currently do with tasks)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed it seems that you can change the colour of an Event, Out-of-office or Appointment-slots type just by right-clicking in the calendar view, but the Reminders and Tasks don't have this feature :-(

There are obviously hundreds of productivity apps out there which allow you much more control over how your organise your tasks and will integrate with Google Calendar.